# Installing Pik in Windows 7 PATH variable naming error

Tags: ruby, windows, cygwin, pik

On installation of Pik, it seems that the directory naming conventions utilized in the program are erroneous, as can be seen below where `C:` is not reconciled as `C:\` for the install directory. I suspect this my be the culprit. My PATH definitely does contain `C:\cygwin64` as a variable, but it isn't recognized by Pik.

I have tried altering the name of the directory as `C:\\cygwin64` during installation as a workaround and other similar variations just for the sake of trial and error, but to no avail. Interestingly, the [Github directory](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/blob/master/bin/pik_install) shows a similar double backslash naming convention for this component, but I'm not sure how this might solve the problem.

The version of Pik I am using is 0.2.8.

```
$ pik_install C:\cygwin64
Thank you for using pik.

mkdir -p C:cygwin64
mkdir -p C:\Users\Adam/.pik
Installing to C:cygwin64

cp /home/Name/.gem/ruby/gems/pik-0.2.8/tools/pik_runner.exe C:cygwin64
cp /home/Name/.gem/ruby/gems/pik-0.2.8/tools/pik.bat C:cygwin64
cp /home/Name/.gem/ruby/gems/pik-0.2.8/tools/pik.ps1 C:cygwin64

creating C:\Users\Name/.pik/.pikrc

pik is installed

The directory you installed to is not in the sytem path.
C:cygwin64

You will need to add it.


if you want to use pik with git bash, add the following line to your ~/.bashrc:

  [[ -s $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc ]] && source $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `/`? `pik_install C:/cygwin64` or just `pik_install /cygwin64`

Comment: Yes I have, they deliver the same result as above.